# Using a created column in a view

Tags: mysql, sql

I've simplifed this to the smallest possible case, so details like "why" might have dissapeared ;-)
I have a database table with 2 columns:

```
A varchar(1) | B (integer)
```

I want to create a view where I add a "total" where `if A = 1 then total = B * 10 else total = B * 5`

e.g.

```
A  B  Total
-----------
1  1  10
1  2  20
2  1  5
2  2  10
```

But I want to know whether I used 10 or 5 as well, so I want a "B Value" column like so:

```
A  B  BVal Total
----------------
1  1  10   10
1  2  10   20
2  1  5    5
2  2  5    10
```

So I tried to create a view:

```
select A, B, (case A when 1 then 10 else 5 end) as Bval, B * Bval as Total from dummy
```

But I get an error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'Bval' in 'field list'`. Is there anyway to make this work in a single view?

---

For anyone wanting enough info to DIY:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dummy` (
  `A` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `B` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `dummy`
--

INSERT INTO `dummy` (`A`, `B`) VALUES
('A', 1),
('A', 2),
('B', 1),
('B', 2);

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `dummyview` 
    AS SELECT `dummy`.`A`, `dummy`.`B`, 
    (case `dummy`.`A` when 1 then 10 else 5 end) as `BVal`, 
    `dummy`.`B` * `BVal` as `Total`
    FROM `dummy`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reuse the alias in the same select clause, so you'll have to repeat the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    A,
    B,
    (CASE A WHEN 1 THEN 10 ELSE 5 END) AS Bval,
    B * (CASE A WHEN 1 THEN 10 ELSE 5 END) AS Total
FROM dummy;
```

As to *why* this is the case, the alias is not yet available when the select clause is being evaluated.

Note that you *could* wrap your current query in a subquery to use the `B` alias.  But, don't do that, because it might hurt performance.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed it was because `BVal` didn't exist yet. I've just tested (and it seems to work) that I can have one view calculate BVal and a second view to calculate the total. I think 2 views may be easier to follow (and less error prone) in my real case.

Answer (score 0):

As BVal is calculated field, you need to use inner query like below

```
select
 A,
 B,
 BVal,
 BVal * B as Total
from
    (
     select 
       A, 
       B, 
       (case A when 1 then 10 else 5 end) as Bval
     from dummy) innerQuery
```